# How to edit pass a flag (--ipc=host) to docker run -d -p in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines, cypress

I have an azure pipeline which deploys an express server and Cypress E2E with headless browser on a Docker. after one test, i get a message: 
[527:0108/134726.008962:FATAL:memory.cc(22)] Out of memory. size=262144

> *We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed. You are running Docker (there is an easy fix for this: see link below)
>   https://on.cypress.io/renderer-process-crashed*

Based on cypress bug on docker (https://on.cypress.io/renderer-process-crashed)
I'm trying to add a flag (--ipc=host) to the the command "docker run" in azure pipeline.
Is there a way to that?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Can my answer helps to resolve your puzzle?

Comment: Hello my friend. it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's [one discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3633) about this topic in Github, adding `--ipc=host` or increasing `/dev/shm` size for container seems not to be one good choice for CI system.

Starting Chrome with `--disable-dev-shm-usage` could be one fix for this issue during CI. Since the fix from cypress has not been released, you can track the [#5336](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5336) to get notifications if there's any update. And here's one workaround from [flogwig](https://github.com/flotwig) which may help:

Modify Chrome flags by adding this in pluginsfile:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
    if (browser.family === 'chrome') {
      console.log('Adding --disable-dev-shm-usage...')
      args.push('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    }

    return args
  })
}
```